# Missing drawable folder in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Beginner in Android Studio. Drawable folder missing in Android Studio. I need the drawable folder to change button  backgrounds when pressed.

[image]

Comment: `Missing drawable folder`? Create it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click over `res` and make the `drawable` folder yourself. Choose New > "Android resource directory" from the context menu, choose `drawable` in the "Resource type" drop-down, and click the OK button.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder called drawable.

Or you can rename the mipmap folder to drawable.

R.mipmap.* is also feasible.